# query data created in time with TypeORM

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I want to query and count  data in table at **created** interval  **4 hours** [ 00.00 - 04.00 , 04.01 - 08.00 , 08.01-12.00]
In **QueryBuilder** how to query with this condition

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :

```
await connection
        .getRepository(yourRepo)
        .select()
        .where('createdAt >= :after')
        .andWhere('createdAt < :before')
        .setParameter('after', after)
        .setParameter('before', before)
```

You just need to have 2 variables for the interval.